# Adding css via javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add css to a page. I've written the following code:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssText = ".nav-item > #toolbarmorebutton {display:block;} #itemMore:hover > #toolbarmorebutton{display:block !important;}#toolbarmorebutton {position:fixed;   right:0px;  }";
```

However, it does not seem to work.

NOTE: I need to ADD this to the existing css, not replace it.

Thank you

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't work. Explain the difference between expected and actual outcome.

Comment: Try `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.cssText`

Comment: @Daniel Williams I get an error message Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: @Karl Richter the css rules aren't applied to the html elements. The expected result is that the css rules ARE applied to the html elements. The actual outcome is that they aren't. I'm not sure what else "Doesn't work" can mean...

Comment: To append those styles to existing styles, it should just be a matter of using the += operator, rather than the = operator. Otherwise, what you have there originally looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Create a couple new classes for the styles you need

```
.display-block{
  display:block !important;
}
.toolbarmorebutton-after{
  position:fixed;   
  right:0px;  
}
```

and then use this jQuery to apply it

```
$(".nav-item > #toolbarmorebutton").addClass("display-block");
$("#itemMore:hover > #toolbarmorebutton").addClass("display-block");
$("#toolbarmorebutton").addClass("toolbarmorebutton-after");
```

You can use removeClass to remove the classes when you no longer need it applied
http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

You could also use toggleClass if you needed to toggle between them.
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Thank you. I know how to add to individual elements. However, this CSS contains several elements with several IDs and with selectors, so adding based on ID isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @NimrodYanai I've edited my original answer to a solution I believe will accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: This solution will not suffice. I am building a custom, one line widget (i.e. people will refer to this javascript via a single call to a js file). I cannot start adding classes to the css outside the code. I need to add this line to the css as it is.